# Xamarin iOS change Backgroundcolor after swipe over it

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, custom-renderer

I have a Grid with Buttons and will change the background color if the user swipe over them. 
I created a custom Button class:

```
    public class TouchscreenTestButton : UIButton
{
    public override void TouchesBegan(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
    {
        base.TouchesBegan(touches, evt);
        this.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Green;

    }
    public override void TouchesMoved(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
    {
        base.TouchesMoved(touches, evt);
        UITouch touch = touches.AnyObject as UITouch;
        if (touch != null)
        {

            this.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Green;
            SetNeedsDisplay();
        }
    }
    public override void TouchesEnded(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
    {
        base.TouchesEnded(touches, evt);
        UITouch touch = touches.AnyObject as UITouch;
        if (touch != null)
        {
            this.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Green;
        }
    }
}
```

Also a Button Renderer for replace the normal UIButtons of iOS to my TouchscreenTestButton.

```
    public class TouchscreenTestButtonRenderer : ButtonRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
    {
        int columnIndex = Grid.GetColumn(e.NewElement);
        int rowIndex = Grid.GetRow(e.NewElement);
        TouchscreenTestButton button = new TouchscreenTestButton();
        button.TouchDown +=(sender, evt) => Control.BackgroundColor=UIColor.Green;

        base.SetNativeControl(button);

        base.OnElementChanged(e);
    }
}
```

That doesnt work, only the first button I touch will get a green backgroundcolor. After that I create a Renderer for the Grid:

```
    public class GridRenderer : ViewRenderer
{
    public override void TouchesMoved(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
    {
        base.TouchesMoved(touches, evt);
        var touch = touches.AnyObject as UITouch;
        for (int i = 0; i < touch.View.Subviews.Length; i++)
        {
            var test = touch.LocationInView(this);
            if (PointInside(touch.LocationInView(this), evt))
            {
                this.Subviews[i].TouchesBegan(touches, evt);
                this.Subviews[i].BackgroundColor = UIColor.Green;
                SetNeedsDisplay();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But also this doesnt work. I see that the event is fired and the backgroundcolor of the subview will be changed but the view doesnt update.

Can please somebody help? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just to make sure I did understand: You want to change the background color of a Button (Xamarin.Forms) for an iOS application when the user Swipe on the Button?

Comment: Yes I've created a Grid with buttons and the user can swipe over it and each button the user touched should get a green background color.
I'm not sure if the button is the best control for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have test with the following code on my side , it works.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Grid), typeof(GridRenderer))]
namespace Slide.iOS
{
class GridRenderer :ViewRenderer
{

    public override void TouchesBegan(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
    {
        base.TouchesBegan(touches, evt);
        var touch = touches.AnyObject as UITouch;
        for (int i = 0; i < touch.View.Subviews.Length; i++)
        {
            var test = touch.LocationInView(this);
            var buttonView = touch.View.Subviews[i];

            CGRect frame = buttonView.Frame;

            if (frame.Contains(test))
            { 
                //pay attention
                var button = buttonView.Subviews[0];
                button.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Green;
            }
        }
    }

    public override void TouchesMoved(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
    {
        base.TouchesMoved(touches, evt);
        var touch = touches.AnyObject as UITouch;
        for (int i = 0; i < touch.View.Subviews.Length; i++)
        {
            var test = touch.LocationInView(this);
            var buttonView = touch.View.Subviews[i];

            CGRect frame = buttonView.Frame;

            if (frame.Contains(test)) {
                //pay attention
                var button = buttonView.Subviews[0];
                button.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Green;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Result :

[image]

#### Details:

1.Disable the button in Portable, since the click event will be conflict with the touch event of Grid.

```
<Button BackgroundColor="Red" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" IsEnabled="False"/>
```

2.Determine whether the point you moved to is in the frame of that subview(button).

```
if (frame.Contains(test))
```

3. Look at the **buttonView**, pay attention it was not the button!! I set the backgroundcolor on it at the beginning but it didn't work. When we layout control in a Grid, it will auto generate subviews according to its columns and rows,and then put the controls on the subviews.

e.g

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

The Grid above will have 4 subviews ,and four corresponding buttons on that subviews.

Comment: A small issue, in TouchesBegan you probably meant to call base.TouchesBegan and not base.TouchesMoved